# How to get LCID from CultureInfo in windows 8 app?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

It seems there is no way to get LCID from CultureInfo in windows 8 app, simple:

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("HR-hr");
string id = ci.LCID; /// LCID is private !
```

Is there any other way to get LCID, I need it for legacy WebService that I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, there is no way to get LCID from Windows Store app, so I made a little console app to produce code that will fill Dictionary with all LCID's and I am using that in Windows store app, it's somewhat long code so here is a link:

http://www.antoniob.com/get-lcid-in-windows-store-apps.html